# Regular expression not behaving as expected

Tags: python, html, regex

I have the following function which is supposed to read a `.html` file and search for `<input>` tags, and inject a `<input type='hidden'>` tag into the string to be shown into the page.
However, that condition is never met:( e.g the `if` statement is never executed. ) What's wrong with my regex?

```
 def print_choose( params, name ):

   filename = path + name
   f = open( filename, 'r' )
   records = f.readlines()
   print "Content-Type: text/html"
   print
   page = ""
   flag = True
   for record in records:
        if re.match( '<input*', str(record) ) != None:
            print record
            page += record
            page += "<input type='hidden' name='pagename' value='psychology' />"
        else:
            page += record

   print page
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`re.match` starts at the very first char in the string. Are you sure you don't want `re.search`, which can match patterns in the middle of your string?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>    if re.match( '<input*', str(record) ) != None:
> ```

You probably want `<input.*`. Right now you would match on `<inputttttttttt` but not `<input>blahblah`. The `.` indicates any character and the * indicates 0 or matches to the last item in the regex, so `.*` asks to repeatedly wildcard match on 0 or more chars.

(PS check out [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) for regex debugging)

Comment: This is true, but not why his `if` isn't being triggered.

Comment: @DSM probably because of Kirk's answer.

Comment: @DougT.: yep, he beat me while I was copy-'n-pasting the docs. :^)

Comment: @DSM I am as a thief in the night.